# Grails 2 level deep belongsTo gives transient instance error

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Is it possible to have 2 levels deep belongsTo in Grails? I can't seem to make it work in Grails 2.2.2.

Here are my models

```
class Content {
    static constraints = {
        key(unique: true, blank: false)
        title(blank: true)
    }

    static mapping = {
    }

    static hasMany = [elements: Element]

    String title
    String key
}

class Element {
    static belongsTo = [content: Content]

    static constraints = {
        textElement(nullable: true)
    }

    TextElement textElement
}

class TextElement {
    static constraints = {
        title(nullable: true)
        subTitle(nullable: true)
        text(blank: false, markdown: true, widget: 'textarea')
    }

    static belongsTo = [element: Element]

    String title
    String subTitle
    String text
}
```

In the controller, I bind and save using the following sample code

```
def par = [key: 'akey', title: 'atitle', 'elements[0].textElement.text': 'atext']
def content = new Content(par)
content.save(flush: true)
```

I am getting a org.hibernate.TransientObjectException which makes me wonder if having nested belongsTo is possible in Grails (or Hibernate)

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: TextElement
```

Of course everything works if I drop a belongsTo and save each textElement prior to saving the content.

Thanks!

Comment: I would use addTo* on your Content class when adding elements so that bidirectional references are updated automatically. Check [addTo](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/addTo.html) docs.

Comment: I am not sure this would work. The relation from Element and TextElement is not a collection but a reference. Currently, I removed the TextElements : `belongsTo` and save them prior to saving the Content in the controller.